# Register generic Action Filter with multiple types from DI container

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, custom-action-filter

I'm working on an `Asp.net core 5` targeted `.net 5`.
I used an `Action filter` as `generic`.
This action filter will check the `model`'s `Id` if any another object has the same `Id` in the `TEntity`.
`TEntity` is the generic type will be replaced by the name of entity to be check-in if an object exist or not.

**What I tried:**

```
public class ShouldExistFilter<TEntity>:IActionFilter where  TEntity : class
{

    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;

    public ShouldExistFilter(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext context )
    {
        context.ActionArguments.TryGetValue( "model" , out object model );

        var result= _dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Find( model.GetType().GetProperty( "Id" ).GetValue( model ) );

        if ( result!=null )
        {
          // Some logic here
        }

       
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext context )
    {
        
    }

}
```

**How I used it with actions:**

1st example:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ShouldExistFilter<SchoolSubject>))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(SchoolSubjectModel model)
{
// Some logic here
}
```

2nd example:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ShouldExistFilter<Student>))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(StudentModel model)
{
// Some logic here
}
```

**The problem:**
When I try to register the `ShouldExistFilter` in `ConfigureServices` method I have to register it with all entities that may I used with the `filter` and this is not practical for me because I have a lot of entities.

**At now I should do :**

```
services.AddScoped<ShouldExistFilter<SchoolSubject>>(); 

services.AddScoped<ShouldExistFilter<Student>>();  
      
services.AddScoped<ShouldExistFilter<Absence>>();

...
```

**The question:**

How can I register the `ShouldExistFilter` one time in `DI Container` and use it with any `Type` ? or is there any way to reach my object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a service filter attribute, you can also use the [`[TypeFilter]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#typefilterattribute) which will allow you to create a filter with dependencies without that filter having to be registered with the DI container itself:

```cs
[TypeFilter(typeof(ShouldExistFilter<SchoolSubject>))]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(SchoolSubjectModel model)
{
    // Some logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like any generic registration you register it as a type

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(ShouldExistFilter<>)));
```